# In D3 I'm assigning a colour to a data category using d3.scale.ordinal(). How can I assign it based on value of x-axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a very large colour array defined as:

```
 .range(["#2b328c", "#C1D42F", "#5AB88D", "#8F1F61", "#00A5D3", "#EC5D20", "#F59C28", "#F8B90B", "#3599B8", "#DFBFBF", "#4AC5BB", "#5F6B6D", "#FB8281", "#F4D25A", "#7F898A", "#A4DDEE", "#FDAB89", "#B687AC", "#28738A", "#A78F8F", "#168980", "#293537", "#BB4A4A", "#B59525", "#475052", "#6A9FB0", "#BD7150", "#7B4F71", "#1B4D5C", "#706060", "#0F5C55", "#1C2325", "#7D3231", "#796419", "#303637", "#476A75", "#7E4B36", "#52354C", "#0D262E", "#544848", "#016AB8", "#373D49", "#FDB15D", "#AAF20F", "#5F646D", "#8AA3EB", "#FEE266", "#A6687A", "#3557B8", "#DFCFBF", "#4A91C5", "#5F646D", "#FBBF81", "#C9F459", "#7F838A", "#A4B8EE", "#FDE489", "#B68794", "#28428A", "#A79B8F", "#165889", "#292E37", "#BB824A", "#8DB525", "#474A52", "#6A7CB0", "#BDA750", "#7B4F5A", "#1B2C5C", "#706860", "#0F3C5C", "#1C1E25", "#7D5731", "#5D7918", "#303237", "#475375", "#7E6F36", "#52343D", "#0D152E", "#544E48", "#010EB8", "#393749", "#F9FD5D", "#38F20F", "#615F6D", "#A08AEB", "#CEFE66", "#A67668", "#5435B8", "#DFDFBF", "#4A53C5", "#615F6D", "#FAFB81", "#7CF459", "#807F8A", "#B5A4EE", "#DBFD89", "#B69087", "#3F288A", "#A7A78F", "#161F89", "#2A2937", "#BBBB4A", "#45B525", "#494752", "#7A6AB0", "#9CBD50", "#7B594F", "#291B5C", "#707060", "#0F155C", "#1E1C25", "#7C7D31", "#2D7918", "#303037", "#514775", "#697E36", "#523B34", "#140D2E", "#545448", "#4E01B8", "#423749", "#A9FD5D", "#0FF256", "#675F6D", "#D18AEB", "#82FE66", "#A69468", "#9535B8", "#CFDFBF", "#7D4AC5", "#675F6D", "#BCFB81", "#59F484", "#857F8A", "#DAA4EE", "#A1FD89", "#B6A887", "#6F288A", "#9BA78F", "#461689", "#322937", "#82BB4A", "#25B54C", "#4E4752", "#9E6AB0", "#65BD50", "#7B6E4F", "#4A1B5C", "#687060", "#2E0F5C", "#221C25", "#567D31", "#187934", "#343037", "#684775", "#457E36", "#524934", "#250D2E", "#4E5448", "#AA01B8", "#493746", "#5DFD62", "#0FF2C7", "#6D5F6B", "#EB8AD3", "#66FE96", "#99A668", "#B83598", "#BFDFBF", "#BA4AC5", "#6D5F6B", "#81FB82", "#59F4D1", "#8A7F89", "#EEA4DD", "#89FDAA", "#ACB687", "#8A2873", "#8FA78F", "#801689", "#372934", "#4ABB4A", "#25B594", "#524750", "#B06A9F", "#50BD70", "#717B4F", "#5C1B4D", "#607060", "#540F5C", "#251C22", "#317D32", "#187964", "#373036", "#75476A", "#367E4A", "#4C5234", "#2E0D26", "#485448", "#B8016A", "#49373D", "#5DFDB1", "#0FAAF2", "#6D5F64", "#EB8AA3", "#66FEE2", "#7AA668", "#B83557", "#BFDFCF", "#C54A91", "#6D5F64", "#81FBBF", "#59C9F4", "#8A7F83", "#EEA4B8", "#89FDE5", "#94B687", "#8A2842", "#8FA79B", "#891658", "#37292E", "#4ABB82", "#258DB5", "#52474A", "#B06A7C", "#50BDA7", "#5B7B4F", "#5C1B2C", "#607068", "#5C0F3C", "#251C1E", "#317D58", "#185D79", "#373032", "#754752", "#367E6F", "#3D5234", "#2E0D15", "#48544E", "#B8010E", "#493937", "#5DF9FD", "#0F38F2", "#6D615F", "#EBA08A", "#66CEFE", "#68A676", "#B85435", "#BFDFDF", "#C54A53", "#6D615F", "#81FAFB", "#597CF4", "#8A807F", "#EEB5A4", "#89DBFD", "#87B691", "#8A3F28", "#8FA7A7", "#89161E", "#372A29", "#4ABBBB", "#2545B5", "#524947", "#B07A6A", "#509CBD", "#4F7B58", "#5C291B", "#607070", "#5C0F15", "#251E1C", "#317C7D", "#182D79", "#373030", "#755147", "#36687E", "#34523B", "#2E140D", "#485454", "#B84E01", "#494337", "#5DA9FD", "#560FF2", "#6D685F", "#EBD18A", "#6681FE", "#68A694", "#B89535", "#BFCFDF", "#C57D4A", "#6D685F", "#81BCFB", "#8459F4", "#8A857F", "#EEDAA4", "#89A1FD", "#87B6A8", "#8A7028", "#8F9BA7", "#894616", "#373229", "#4A82BB", "#4D25B5", "#524E47", "#B09E6A", "#5065BD", "#4F7B6F", "#5C4A1B", "#606870", "#5C2E0F", "#25221C", "#31567D", "#341879", "#373430", "#756947", "#36447E", "#345249", "#2E250D", "#484E54", "#B8A901", "#464937", "#615DFD", "#C70FF2", "#6B6D5F", "#D4EB8A", "#9666FE", "#6898A6", "#99B835", "#BFBFDF", "#C5BA4A", "#6B6D5F", "#8181FB", "#D159F4", "#898A7F", "#DDEEA4", "#AA89FD", "#87ACB6", "#738A28", "#8F8FA7", "#897F16", "#353729", "#4A4ABB", "#9425B5", "#505247", "#9FB06A", "#7050BD", "#4F717B", "#4D5C1B", "#606070", "#5C540F", "#23251C", "#31317D", "#641879", "#363730", "#6A7547", "#4B367E", "#344C52", "#262E0D", "#484854", "#6AB801", "#3D4937", "#B15DFD", "#F20FAA", "#646D5F", "#A3EB8A", "#E266FE", "#687AA6", "#57B835", "#CFBFDF", "#91C54A", "#646D5F", "#BF81FB", "#F459C9", "#838A7F", "#B7EEA4", "#E589FD", "#8794B6", "#428A28", "#9B8FA7", "#588916", "#2E3729", "#824ABB", "#B5258D", "#4A5247", "#7CB06A", "#A750BD", "#4F5B7B", "#2C5C1B", "#686070", "#3C5C0F", "#1E251C", "#57317D", "#79185D", "#323730", "#537547", "#6F367E", "#343D52", "#152E0D", "#4E4854", "#0FB801", "#37493A", "#FD5DF9", "#F20F39", "#5F6D61", "#8AEBA1", "#FE66CE", "#7568A6", "#35B854", "#DFBFDF", "#54C54A", "#5F6D61", "#FB81FA", "#F4597C", "#7F8A80", "#A4EEB5", "#FD89DB", "#9187B6", "#288A3F", "#A78FA7", "#1F8916", "#29372B", "#BB4ABB", "#B52544", "#475249", "#6AB07B", "#BD509B", "#594F7B", "#1B5C2A", "#706070", "#155C0F", "#1C251E", "#7D317B", "#79182D", "#303731", "#477552", "#7E3668", "#3B3452", "#0D2E14", "#544854", "#01B84E", "#374942", "#FD5DA9", "#F2560F", "#5F6D67", "#8AEBD1", "#FE6682", "#9468A6", "#35B895", "#DFBFCF", "#4AC57D", "#5F6D67", "#FB81BD", "#F48459", "#7F8A85", "#A4EEDA", "#FD89A1", "#A887B6", "#288A6F", "#A78F9B", "#168946", "#293732", "#BB4A82", "#B54C25", "#47524E", "#6AB09D", "#BD5065", "#6E4F7B", "#1B5C4A", "#706068", "#0F5C2E", "#1C2522", "#7D3156", "#793418", "#303734", "#477568", "#7E3644", "#493452", "#0D2E25", "#54484E"]);
```

I then assign a colour to a 'brand' when creating my scatter points, as follows:

```
var enterSelection =
    svg.selectAll(".point")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) {
      return d.type == "point"
    }))
    .enter()
    .append("g");


  enterSelection.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return logosize / 7
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.x1);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.y1);
    })
 
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
      
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colors(d.brand);
    })
```

However, when this plots, it appears to assign the colours to a brand based on the value of the x-axis, smallest to largest, see screenshot below:

[image]

How would I flip the assignment so that the first colours in the array are assigned to the largest x-axis values rather than the smallest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set your domain (I'm assuming you don't), D3 will create the ordinal scale's domain based on the usage:

> Setting the domain on an ordinal scale is optional if the unknown value is implicit (the default). In this case, the domain will be inferred implicitly from usage by assigning each unique value passed to the scale a new value from the range. [(source)](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#ordinal_domain)

Therefore, it's a good idea to explicitly set the domain. Since you want that...

> the first colours in the array are assigned to the largest x-axis values

...we can sort the data and create a `brand` array:

```
.domain(data.sort((a, b) => b.x1 - a.x1).map(d => d.brand))
```

Pay attention to the fact that `sort()` will change your data array in place.